# Infinite system of equations with finitely many constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

During my research I have stumbled upon the following issue concerning infinite systems of linear equations. I do not have much practice in such settings, so I am asking you whether the following connotes or reminds you something — perhaps there is already some developed theory of such or similar systems.

We work in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ endowed with pointwise addition and multiplication by scalars. Let $(\varphi_n \colon\ n\in\mathbb{N})$ be a sequence of functionals such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist $k_1,\ldots,k_m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ we have

$$\varphi_n(x)=\alpha_1x(k_1)+\dots+\alpha_mx(k_m)$$

(so $\varphi_n$ is a linear combination of some Dirac's delta on $\mathbb{N}$) and $|\alpha_1|+\ldots+|\alpha_m|=1$. Let $G$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, $g\colon G\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

Does there exist $x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ satisfying the following conditions?

1. there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $l\ge n$ we have $\varphi_l(x)=0$.
2. for every $k\in G$ we have $|g(k)-x(k)|<\varepsilon$.

Do you know whether such or similar problems have been already considered somewhere? Maybe they already have a name, so I can easier look for some results? I'll be grateful for any hint!

PS. I posted this question to Math.SE, but the response has been null.

Comment: You should assume something about $k_1,\dots,k_m$ to make it meaningful. If this set coincides with $G$ for all $\varphi_n$, for instance, you are surely in trouble. On the other hand, if each next $\varphi_{n+1}$ uses a new variable that wasn't used in $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n$, there is no problem whatsoever. The rest of the cases are in between and, I suspect, should be dealt with on a case by case basis, so you'd better tell us the actual setting.